# Restrict access to Website based on Geographical location

Tags: c#, geolocation

I want to put restriction like certain Regions, Cities and Countries should not be able to access my website. I came across some concept like GeoFencing, but I guess that can only be implemented on Windows Phones Or Windows 10. I came across few free APIs that would return me my client's location details.

I am working with Visual Studio 2015.

I also came across HTML5 GoeLocation, it is will ask user for permission to allow website to know his/her location; which is not good enough for me.

I want to know, what are other better choices or solutions we can look into?

Also, since I am using IIS server for deployment, can I use .htaccess in my case?

I have came across this  [IPSecurity configuration](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)  at server level. Is this a viable option? Has anyone tried it?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things you can try to do to find out the location of the user.

As you already found you can request their location from their browser, but that requires asking their permission, and it can be unreliable.

The location can be manually set, and in the case of desktop computers it's unlikely the computer has a GPS attached to provide a good location.

Another option is to look up thier IP in a geoip database: [GeoIP2 City Database Demo](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo)

There does appear to be a GeoIP module for IIS 7+, but I haven't tried it personally: [IIS7 Geoblock Module](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iis7geoblockmod/)

**But**, these methods are unreliable and can give indeterminate, or even flat out wrong results.

The user can decline to provide their browser location, or the user can set their browser location to be the other side of the world.

And what IP is the user using? What about if they use a VPN? Now you have the geolocation for the VPNs IP.

The real answer is that you can't reliably find out where the end user is.

**.htaccess**

.htaccess is one of the ways [Apache allows configuring security](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

IIS uses different configuration methods.

Both IIS and Apache require 3rd party modules to restrict access based on geolocation, it's not something provided as standard.

Comment: I know we cannot locate our users with 100% accuracy. I just want to know whether there are other options to look into. I have found something here [link](https://forums.iis.net/t/1167621.aspx)

Comment: I added a link to a geoip module for IIS. But there aren't many around, because they don't work ;)

Comment: I just tried two IPs in the GeoIP2 database demo, my work IP and my home IP. My work IP resolved correctly to my location, but my home IP resolved to 225km away. The GeoIP2 database is $24 a month for Country resolution, or $100 a month for City resolution. Here's more info about the average accuracy for different countries: https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-database-accuracy